# Common Source Amplifier Pmos?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, amplifier, analog

What is known as a common source amplifier is often built with an NMOS, where the bottom channel (source) is connected to ground. What if you switch out the NMOS with a PMOS, and the bottom channel is now really a drain connected to ground, is it still called a "Common Source Amplifier"? And is the gain still negative?

Thank you in advance

Comment: A PMOS Common Source amplifier would connect source to V+, and drain via a load (e.g. R) to V-/Gnd. Input voltage would be referred to V+ and output taken from drain as normal. What you are describing is ... well see AudioGuru's answer.

Answer (score 1):

A P-channel Mosfet with its drain grounded is a source-follower (common-drain) with a gain of a little less than 1 and no inversion.